# scrollView is nil when called from viewdidload

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to scrolling view when navigationItem clicked.
But..here is some error.

1. I want to make snapchatlike scroll view.
   It works fine, but... when I call scrollView out of viewdidload function, scrollView is nil!
2. I already make snapchat like swipe view. but I want to make swipe view when navigation Item(heart mark) clicked.

My ViewController viewdidload func - it works fine

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


var V1 : LeftViewController = LeftViewController(nibName: "LeftViewController", bundle: nil)
var V2 : CenterViewController = CenterViewController(nibName: "CenterViewController", bundle: nil)
var V3 : RightViewController = RightViewController(nibName: "RightViewController", bundle: nil)



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.addChildViewController(V1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
    V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(V2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
    V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(V3)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(V3.view)
    V3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
    V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    V2.view.frame = V2Frame


    var V3Frame : CGRect = V3.view.frame
    V3Frame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
    V3.view.frame = V3Frame

    println(self)
    println(scrollView)
    println(V2.view.frame)

    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(V2Frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height), animated: false)



    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height)        }
```

My ViewController clickEvent func - why scrollView is nil?

```
    func clickEvent() {

    self.scrollView?.scrollRectToVisible(V2.view.frame, animated: true)

    println(self)
    println(scrollView)
    println(V2.view.frame)
    //self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(V2.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height), animated: true)
}
```

I call clickEvent in Viewcontroller from other CenterViewController
- it can call fine but...in ViewController clickEvent functions' scrollView is nil.. How can I fix it?

```
func clickEvent(sender: AnyObject) {

   ViewController().clickEvent()
}
```

Comment: These lines: 
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 320.0, height: 568.0))
and
self.scrollView?.scrollRectToVisible(V2.view.frame, animated: true)
refer to different scroll views.

Comment: Yes, I added that code because scrollView is nil.... how can I get the same scrollView ...?

Answer (score 1):

in your code you get and set a view frame In `viewDidLoad`. In `viewDidLoad` views are only loaded in memory but not yet in screen, so if you try to ask a view for its frame in `viewDidLoad` you will Not get a consistante value..
Instead use `viewWillAppear` where you can ask view for its frame and you get a right value since the view is ready to be shown.

Comment: u mean, rewrite the code from viewdidload to viewwillapper? .. its not working...

Comment: the part of code dealing with views  related to size, frame,

Answer (score 0):

The class itself does not contain the layout information in it. So there is no way the view controller object know which view object is connected to which IBOutlet. The view controller have to be instantiated through storyboard itself. You can use the following methods

```
storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR_VC_STORYBOARD_ID")
```

When you use the second method don't forget to set the Storyboard Identifier.
You can find the place to enter the identifier when you go to View Controller -> Identity Inspector -> Storyboard_ID

Comment: I wrote that code to. viewdidload or clickevent func in viewcontroller and centerviewcontroller. but Its not working

Comment: How did you wrote that code could you show me? And did you connect the IBOutlet properly??